# Cannot Run Excel Add-in Functions

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-addins

I have an Excel AddIn that I load from a C# file. On a spreadsheet, I am able to call functions from this AddIn without trouble, however, I am unable to do so using VBA.

Suppose the name of the addin is "ExcelAddIn" and the class in question is "Functions". In VBA, I have made available the reference (via Tools > References) and I would have expected the following to work:

```
Dim addin As ExcelAddIn.Functions
Set addin = New ExcelAddIn.Functions

result = addin.ArbitraryFunction(...)
```

But this gives me an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. I am confused because calling "=ArbitraryFunction(...)" in any cell works just fine. My question is: **why might the addin function fail with VBA, but otherwise works fine on the sheet?**

I realize that this error suggests something on the C# side is not instantiating correctly. The argugment types for "ArbitraryFunction" are both objects and Doubles (I am quite sure this is not an issue though). While I cannot show you the code, I will describe what I think is the culprit. In "ArbitraryFunction", I try to use a "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application" object. I suspect that I am not correctly instantiating this. As required, the C# code has a "OnConnection" function: perhaps my approaches in VBA does not trigger this function?

Any help, comments or suggestions is appreciated. For the time being, I am using Application.Evaluate() to get by, but this is far from ideal. I am trying to keep my work-stream and calculations in VBA, as I have a lot of number crunching to do.

Thanks!

**Update**

I tried to manually call the `OnConnection` function in my C# code, using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/extensibility.idtextensibility2.onconnection?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) for reference. It seems this approach is in the right direction, in so far as I no longer get the error described above. However, I am now met with the new error upon calling:

```
Dim connect_mode As AddInDesignerObjects.ext_ConnectMode
connect_mode = ext_cm_AfterStartup

Call addin.OnConnection(Application, connect_mode, addin, Nothing)
```

Which gives a rather strange error pop-up with the message "Value does not fall within the expected range". The error is strange because it does not stop the code, rather just pops-up without crashing the code. Thoughts?

Comment: Possibly you need to set a reference to the add-in in the VBA UI (Tools/References)

Comment: If by that you mean, clicking the checkbox in the UI then unfortunately I have already done so. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Did you do that in the **VBA** editor (as well as in the Excel Options editor).

Comment: Indeed so. Seeing as I am able to set the reference, I do not believe there is any issue there. It is calling the function that gives the error. In fact, if I specify the number of parameters, as expected, I get an error indicating so. This tells me I am able to access the functions from the addin, but there is some reference not being set correctly in the C# code.

Comment: hopefully someone knowledgeable in C# will respond.

Comment: If you have the addin loaded, do you see it in object browser within vba? I dont think you may need to instantiate it because it is already loaded (and you are able to call it from within a excel cell).

Comment: Yes, it appears in the object browser after instantiating it as I show above. Without instantiating, I am unable to access the functions at all. Quite frustrating!

Comment: Are you sure `Functions` is a class?   Having referenced the addin, maybe all you need is `ExcelAddIn.Functions.ArbitraryFunction(...)`

Comment: Yes. It is a public class public implementing IDTExtensibility2. Without instantiating, `ExcelAddIn.Functions.ArbitraryFunction(...)` throws "Method or data member not found" for Functions.

Comment: [This might help](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/automationaddins.aspx) , in particular the section headed _Using Automation Functions In VBA_

Comment: Appreciate the reference, unfortunately no luck. If we can entertain the idea that the `OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst,ref Array custom)` function is not being called correctly when I create the AddIn object from VBA, how would I manually trigger this function? I suggest this because in `ArbitraryFunction(...)`, I referenced a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application' object, and I think that is what's throwing the error. Thanks everyone for helping!